# EF Core 1.1 generating unique index on FK one-to-one

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm using EF Core 1.1 and created my one-to-one relationships, an example:

```
EntityTypeBuilder<Account>
   .HasOne(a => a.Customer)
   .WithOne(a => a.Account)
   .HasForeignKey<Account>(a => a.CustomerId)
```

Now using Add-Migration on my DbContext it generates the following:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
   name: "IX_Accounts_CustomerId",
   table: "Accounts",
   column: "CustomerId",
   unique: true);
```

Is there a way to specify in Fluent to remove the uniqueness from the index? I don't mind the index being generated, but for my purposes it can not be unique. The reason is that these tables are auditable so there can be duplicate data (outside of the PK). Hence records can contain the same FK id if there were no changes to that FK entity (but maybe changes elsewhere in the record).

TL;DR Any way of making the index non-unique in Fluent for one-to-one FKs?

Comment: If the table can contain duplicates, then it's not `one-to-one`, but `one-to-many`, don't you think?

Answer (score 6):

If you want to make the index backing the foreign key non-unique, you need to configure the index on FK property in fluent api and set it to be non-unique.
In you example adding following line of code in `OnModelCreating()` method will give you desired result.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Account>().HasIndex(e => e.CustomerId).IsUnique(false);
```

Though having duplicate values in FK property for one-to-one relationship can have undesired implications at runtime while fixing up navigation properties.

Comment: That didn't work for me.  It still created the unique index.

Comment: Can we add a feature for one-to-one mapping where we can designate the FK to be non-unique-index and if this is the case, EF would automatically restrict cascade deletes?

Comment: BTW, there is no OnModelConfiguring() so I assume you're talking about OnModelCreating().  If not, the only other method I see in DbContext is OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder), and I don't think this is what you're talking about.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and after many trials (Based on [this](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/10826#issuecomment-361740519)) I've realized that the relation should be one to many (or many to one).
I think what happened to you and me was a misunderstanding (or a bad mental effort maybe)

`WithOne()` is replaced by `WithMany()`